# How to intercept inherited method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I want to build a Java agent with Byte Buddy, which intercepts JDBC connection creation and closing event. I want to support data sources such as HikariCP, DBCP, etc, also plain JDBC with RDBMS drivers.

My code:

#### Instrumention setup

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(startMatcher.and(isSubTypeOf(java.sql.Connection.class).and(not(isAbstract())))
                .transform(constructorTransformer).transform(methodsTransformer).with(listener).installOn(inst);
```

#### Intercepting code

```java
package org.wxt.xtools.agents.jdbcmon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.wxt.xtools.agents.utils.StringUtils;
import org.wxt.xtools.agents.utils.TopN;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import io.prometheus.client.Histogram;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.This;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;

/**
 * 
 * @author ggfan
 * 
 */
public class JDBCAPIInterceptor {

    // ***ATTENTION*** fields below must be public, as we will access them from the
    // intercepting methods
    public static Map<Integer, ConnectionInfo> conns = new HashMap<Integer, ConnectionInfo>();
    
    public static Map<String, String> stacks = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static Map<String, Integer> counstsByStack = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    
    public static TopN<StatementExecutionInfo> slowStatements = new TopN<StatementExecutionInfo>(10, new Comparator<StatementExecutionInfo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(StatementExecutionInfo o1, StatementExecutionInfo o2) {
            long d1 = o1.getExecutionEndTime() - o1.getExecutionStartTime();
            long d2 = o2.getExecutionEndTime() - o2.getExecutionStartTime();
            return Long.compare(d1, d2);
        }
    });

    public static Logger log = JDBCMonitor.log;

    public static JDBCStatsReport getInfo() {
        JDBCStatsReport report = new JDBCStatsReport();
        List<ConnectionInfo> data = new ArrayList<ConnectionInfo>();
        for (ConnectionInfo ci : conns.values()) {
            ConnectionInfo copy = new ConnectionInfo();
            copy.setHash(ci.getHash());
            copy.setStackHash(ci.getStackHash() + "(" + counstsByStack.get(ci.getStackHash()) + ")");
            copy.setCreationTime(ci.getCreationTime());
            copy.setLastActiveTime(ci.getLastActiveTime());
            copy.setLastMethod(ci.getLastMethod());
            copy.setCurrentStatement(ci.getCurrentStatement());
            data.add(copy);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        }
        report.setConnectionInfo(data);
        report.setSlowStatementTopN(slowStatements);
        return report;
    }

    @RuntimeType
    public static Object interceptor(@Origin Class<?> clazz, @Origin Method method, @SuperCall Callable<?> callable,
            @net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.This Object inst, @AllArguments Object[] args)
            throws Exception {
        // this is equal to original method, will not cause inner calls to other
        // matching methods get intercepted.
        // Object o = callable.call();
        log.debug("intercepting {}#{}", clazz.getName(), method.getName());
        int hashCode = System.identityHashCode(inst);
        if (java.sql.Connection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            ConnectionInfo ci = conns.get(hashCode);
            // TODO fix bug here!!!
            if (ci == null) {
                log.debug("connection@{} is not in records anymore, maybe called #{} after close, ignored", hashCode,
                        method.getName());
            }
            return interceptConnectionMethods(method, hashCode, ci, callable, args);
        } else if (java.sql.Statement.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return interceptStatementMethods(method, hashCode, callable, args);
        } else if (java.sql.PreparedStatement.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return interceptStatementMethods(method, hashCode, callable, args);
        } else if (java.sql.CallableStatement.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return interceptStatementMethods(method, hashCode, callable, args);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Object interceptConnectionMethods(Method method, int hashCode, ConnectionInfo ci,
            Callable<?> callable, Object[] args) throws Exception {
        Object o = callable.call();
        log.debug("connection@{} used by {}", hashCode, method.getName());
        ci.setLastActiveTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ci.setLastMethod(method.getName());
        int resultHash = System.identityHashCode(o);
        if (method.getName().equals("close")) {
            log.info("connection@{} released", hashCode);
            String stackHash = ci.getStackHash();
            Integer scount = counstsByStack.get(stackHash);
            if (scount != null && scount > 0) {
                int newscount = scount - 1;
                log.info("set connection count to {} by stack hash {}", newscount, stackHash);
                if (newscount == 0) {
                    counstsByStack.remove(stackHash);
                    stacks.remove(stackHash);
                } else {
                    counstsByStack.put(stackHash, newscount);
                }
            } else {
                log.error("connection count by stack hash {} is not supposed to be null or less than zero", stackHash);
            }
            conns.remove(hashCode);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("createStatement")) {
            StatementExecutionInfo stmt = new StatementExecutionInfo();
            stmt.setType(StatementType.NORMAL);
            stmt.setHash(resultHash);
            conns.get(hashCode).setCurrentStatement(stmt);
            log.info("statement@{} created, type {}, attached to connection@{}", resultHash, StatementType.NORMAL, hashCode);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("prepareStatement")) {
            StatementExecutionInfo stmt = new StatementExecutionInfo();
            stmt.setType(StatementType.PREPARED);
            stmt.setSqlText((String) args[0]);
            stmt.setHash(resultHash);
            conns.get(hashCode).setCurrentStatement(stmt);
            log.info("statement@{} created, type {}, attached to connection@{}", resultHash, StatementType.PREPARED, hashCode);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("prepareCall")) {
            StatementExecutionInfo stmt = new StatementExecutionInfo();
            stmt.setType(StatementType.CALLABLE);
            stmt.setSqlText((String) args[0]);
            stmt.setHash(resultHash);
            conns.get(hashCode).setCurrentStatement(stmt);
            log.info("statement@{} created, type {}, attached to connection@{}", resultHash, StatementType.CALLABLE, hashCode);
        }
        return o;
    }

    private static Object interceptStatementMethods(Method method, int hashCode, Callable<?> callable, Object[] args)
            throws Exception {
        log.info("intercepting statement method {}", method.getName());
        Object o = null;
        ConnectionInfo containingCI = conns.values().stream().filter(c -> c.getCurrentStatement().getHash() == hashCode)
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (containingCI == null) {
            log.warn("unexpected situation happened: statement can't found containing connection!");
        }
        if (method.getName().equals("close")) {
            o = callable.call();
            // TODO statement close method not intercepted ??
            if (containingCI != null) {
                containingCI.setCurrentStatement(null);
                log.info("statement@{} closed, detached from connection@{}", hashCode, containingCI.getHash());
            }
        }
        // all statement execution method trigger
        else if (method.getName().startsWith("execute")) {
            String stack = getCurrentThreadStackTrace();
            String stackHash = StringUtils.md5(stack);
            stacks.put(stackHash, stack);
            log.info("statement@{} {} started by {}", hashCode, method.getName(), stackHash);
            long est = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (containingCI != null) {
                containingCI.getCurrentStatement().setExecutionStartTime(est);
                containingCI.getCurrentStatement().setStackHash(stackHash);
                containingCI.getCurrentStatement().setExecutionCallStack(stack);
                if (args.length > 0) {
                    containingCI.getCurrentStatement().setSqlText((String) args[0]);
                }
            }
            Histogram.Timer timer = JDBCMetrics.SQL_EXECUTION_TIME.startTimer();
            try {
                o = callable.call();
            } finally {
                timer.observeDuration();
            }
            long eet = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.info("statement@{} {} finished, duration is {}", hashCode, method.getName(), (eet - est));
            if (containingCI != null) {
                containingCI.getCurrentStatement().setExecutionEndTime(eet);
                slowStatements.add(containingCI.getCurrentStatement());
            }
        }
        return o;
    }

    public static String getCurrentThreadStackTrace() throws IOException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Throwable t = new Throwable("");
        t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String stackTrace = sw.toString();
        sw.close();
        return stackTrace;
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void intercept(@net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.Origin Constructor<?> m, @This Object inst)
            throws Exception {
        log.debug("----------------- constructor intercept -------------------------");
        if (java.sql.Connection.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getDeclaringClass())) {
            // some CP library override hashCode method
            int hashCode = System.identityHashCode(inst);
            ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();
            ci.setHash(hashCode);
            ci.setCreationTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String stackTrace = getCurrentThreadStackTrace();
            String shash = StringUtils.md5(stackTrace);
            stacks.put(shash, stackTrace);
            // ci.setStack(stackTrace);
            ci.setStackHash(shash);
            log.info("connection@{} acquired by stack@{}", hashCode, shash);
            log.debug(stackTrace);
            conns.put(hashCode, ci);
            Integer scount = counstsByStack.get(ci.getStackHash());
            if (scount == null) {
                counstsByStack.put(ci.getStackHash(), 1);
            } else {
                counstsByStack.put(ci.getStackHash(), scount + 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, this will not work for some cases. Take HikariCP for example:

HikariCP's implementation has an abstract class `ProxyConnection`, which has the `close` method implemented, then a class `HikariProxyConnection` extends `ProxyConnection`, which overides some methods, except `close`. If I setup instrumentation on `HikariProxyConnection`, the `close` method will not be intercepted. If I change my code to:

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(startMatcher.and(isSubTypeOf(java.sql.Connection.class).and(isAbstract()))
                .transform(constructorTransformer).transform(methodsTransformer).with(listener).installOn(inst);
```

it will work for HikariCP, but not for other connection pool implementations.

For my use case, is there a unified way? No matter what connection pool is used, and even with plain JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Your matcher:

```
isSubTypeOf(java.sql.Connection.class).and(not(isAbstract())
```

explicitly excludes abstract classes. You would need to instrument all methods to achieve what you wanted if you are using `Advice`.

Also, it seems like you are blending concepts:

```
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.This;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;
```

The latter annotations belong to `MethodDelegation`, not to `Advice`. Refer to the javadoc to see how advice should be applied.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "You would need to instrument all methods to achieve what you wanted if you are using Advice" ? I can remove matcher `not(isAbstract())`,  but then both constructors of `HikariProxyConnection` and `ProxyConnection` will be intercepted, while only one connection instance created.

Comment: I am mixing `Advice` and `MethodDelegation`, `Advice` for constructor  and `MethodDelegation` for other methods, from my testing, it works...man I know you are the author of byte-buddy, but you talk on high level, I can't get you.

Comment: my purpose is to monitor jdbc connection creation and closing events, for creation event I choose to intercept constrcutor of `HikariProxyConnection`, for closing event, I need to intercept `close` method, `close` method is implemented on `ProxyConnection`, while `HikariProxyConnection` extends 'ProxyConnection', it didn't override `close` method, Of course  I can set up instrumention for hikari more precisely, but I want to build a general purpose jdbc monitor, so I am wondering if it's possible to set up instrumention against JDBC api, other than specific implementations.

Comment: This should be possible by instrumenting all classes that implement an interface. To me it seems like you are using the right approach. However, if you exclude abstract classes, you might miss a method that is non-abstract but that is declared by an abstract class. If this is for example an abstract delegator class, you would not get hold of everything. Other than that, JDBC is an SPI. This means that some methods are only declared by abstract classes within the official JDBC namespace.

Comment: maybe you can consider this as a valid use case, add some api to make it easier for client code, if that's possible. from user's perspective, we see java object instances, which has methods from a classes hierarchy, maybe byte-buddy  can handle classes hierarchy then let client code to just choose which method to intercept, on a object instance.

Comment: You can use `Advice` as `Implementation` rather then visitor. This way, Byte Buddy overrides methods in a class also if they are declared by a super type. Is this what you are out after? In this case, apply `Advice.to(...).wrap(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)` the same way you apply `MethodDelegation`.

Comment: applied your suggestion: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot represent public java.sql.Statement com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.createStatement() throws java.sql.SQLException as given method constant`

Comment: Are you filtering abstract methods here?